# How to Customize Bootstrap Carousel Controls

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can you please let me know how I can customize the Bootstrap Carousel Controls for example I would like to change the size of the controls, or bg colors and How I can add background image to the controls?
I tried to replace the **‹** with bootstrap Icons but they positioned at the top of control and didn't work properly

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="prev"><i class=" icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i></a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
```

the output looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can't you use CSS? Is that what you're asking how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How familiar are you with CSS?

What I see in your screenshot could be adjusted via font-size and line-height properties

Bootstrap is a CSS framework so customization is just a matter of overriding defaults, often using an id tag or something similar

Answer (score 2):

one quick way to change the colour is to override the inline svg background:

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

look for the `fill='%23fff'` part and change the colour, from white to something else: `fill='%23444'` or `fill='RoyalBlue'`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for the size and color:

```
.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next {
    font-size: 100px; 
    margin-top: -50px;
    color: #fff;
}
```